# React-UseState hook-> state update does not re-render the page immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Trying to understand the state update -UseState React hook. setting the message inside onchange event of text area re-renders immediately and able to see the updated message state (`handleChangeMessage`).
But while updating the state inside the on-Keypress event doesn't display the updated message text immediately (`handleKeyPressMessage`).

Why the handleKeyPressMessage- doesn't render the latest value but handleChangeMessage does?
The Irony here is the log statement inside handleKeyPress executes first before the onchange event.

> code-sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-01-forked-lvyio?file=/src/index.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Message = () => {
  const [handleChangeMessage, setHandleChangeMessage] = useState("");
  const [sendButtonClass, setSendButtonClass] = useState("send-disabled");
  const [handleKeyPressMessage, setHandleKeyPressMessage] = useState("");

  const handlechange = (e) => {
    console.log("change");
    setHandleChangeMessage(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    console.log("key");
    setHandleKeyPressMessage(e.target.value);
    if (handleChangeMessage == "") {
      setSendButtonClass("send-disabled");
    } else {
      setSendButtonClass("send");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={handleChangeMessage}
        placeholder="Enter a message"
        onChange={handlechange}
        onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
      />
      <button className={sendButtonClass}>Send</button>
      <p>
        "message updated via onChange event ======> : "
        <strong>{handleChangeMessage}</strong>
        <br />
        "message updated via onKeyPress event =====> : "
        <strong>{handleKeyPressMessage}</strong>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Message />, rootElement);
```

> UPDATE

> The issue here is keypress event is triggered first before onchange event(updates handleChangemessage). So the input element  has the outdated value in HandleKeyPress event(e.target.value i.e handleChangemessage)
> Changing the keypress event to keyup will resolve the issue as
> Abhishek suggested

Answer (score 1):

In Place of

```
onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
```

Use

```
onKeyUp={handleKeyPress}
```

Comment: Please let me know if you face any issue

Comment: Got it Abishek, updated the question too.. thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! In my case, I was using `onChange` and `onKeyPress` was being fired before `onChange`, knowing this subtle difference solved it!

Answer (score 0):

event.target returns the element that triggered event. Since the event is triggered by user pressing the key, there is no such element. You should check if your e.target.value returns undefined. If it does, then obtain the value from your input field by giving it unique ID, using something like:

```
const handleKeyPress = (e) => { console.log("key"); setHandleKeyPressMessage(document.getElementById("your-input-id").value); };
```

Comment: Onkeypress I'm invoking the `handleKeyPress` function /event handler which will update `handleKeyPressMesaage`

Comment: Open your console and try to find out if the event is actually triggered or not. You can do that by adding some console.log statements

Comment: Yes log statements are already there.. and event is getting triggered

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it might not be a good thing that should be assumed in the implementation level to rely on. similar to following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481722/10321531)

keypress fires before on-change and doesn't have access to a new value which is going to be bound to the input element.

1. change event triggers event handler `handlechange`
2. update state (`handlechange`) asynchronously
3. bind new value `handlechange` to the input element and cause re-render.

---

but you can access the key property on the event to get the last pressed key and contacting that to the previous keyPress state

```js
const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
  console.log("key"); // to see the input value in this stage e.target.value
  setHandleKeyPressMessage(e.target.value + e.key);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Amir , got the flaw in the code, changing the event to keyUp also works good